# How do I change the footnote style of \thanks to a letter?

Tags: footnotes, titles

I need to have a lowercase superscript letter for the footnote for the author, that is, I need the `\thanks` command to have footnote `a` as opposed to `*`. I'm assuming that I either need to use an option in the `\thanks` command or redefine footnote and then use `\footnote`. I've made various attempts but so far have had no luck.

My document class is `article`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx. I've formatted your inline code by enclosing it in backticks. You can also format code by selecting it, and clicking the `{}` symbol in the editor. Furthermore, I've removed the "Thanks" part from your question: On this site, we don't usually use greetings and thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`titling` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titling) allows you to adjust the `\maketitle` and `\thanks` commands. To use letters instead of symbols for the title footnotes, you would issue `\thanksmarkseries{alph}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titling}

\thanksmarkseries{alph}
\author{N.E. One\thanks{With generous help from E. Veryone}}
\title{Of Odds and End}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are probably many ways to achieve this, but one of the easier ones must be to load the `titling` package and to issue the command `\thanksmarkseries{alph}` in the preamble.